# Sort one table by two rules

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, and would like to sort by following rule.
I  do the SQL as:
`(1) select * from table orderby rank;`
`(2) select * from table orderby LENGTH(str);`
but how can I combine those two SQLs base on (if rank>0) statment?
the idea would be like
`subTable_1 which rank>0, than sort by rank;`
`subTable_2 which rank==0, than sort by str.length;`
result=subTable_1 + subTable_2;
Many thanks

---

table:
| str        |rank|
| ab        | 2    |
| abcd    | 5    |
| abc      | 0    |
| a          | 0    |

result:
| str        |rank|
| abcd    | 5    |
| ab        | 2    |
| a          | 0    |
| abc      | 0    |

Comment: ... Order by rank desc, length(str)

Comment: You should accept answer if it serves your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple. Just try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY rank DESC, LENGTH(str) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since rank of 0 will always be last in the list when sorted DESC, you can use the simple order by that sawrar026 shows:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY rank DESC, LENGTH(str)
```

If you had a different condition, or if rank could be negative and you only wanted to sort where it was zero, you'd want two case statements, so you can control the order, changing the criteria in the case statements to suit:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN rank>0 THEN rank ELSE 0 END DESC
         ,CASE WHEN rank=0 THEN LENGTH(str) ELSE 0 END
```